# Best way to break a string on the last dot on C#

Tags: c#, string

What would be the best way and more idiomatic to break a string into two at the place of the last dot? Basically separating the extension from the rest of a path in a file path or URL. So far what I'm doing is Split(".") and then String.Join(".") of everything but the last part. Sounds like using a bazooka to kill flies.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want performance, something like:

```
    string s = "a.b.c.d";
    int i = s.LastIndexOf('.');
    string lhs = i < 0 ? s : s.Substring(0,i),
        rhs = i < 0 ? "" : s.Substring(i+1);
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use **Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension()**

or if that won't work for you:

```
int idx = filename.LastIndexOf('.');

if (idx >= 0)
   filename = filename.Substring(0,idx);
```

Comment: Will that work on pieces of URL (using / instead of \\)? And will it also return the "folders"? Path.GetFilename() returns only the name of the file, without directories, AFAIK.

Comment: If the OP had asked about file paths only, this would be a +1. But the System.IO.Path docs don't mention support for URLs.

Comment: Correct, but it may have worked for you if the filename didn't include a path.

Comment: It might work, but unfortunately that means relying on an undocumented feature. If that's fine for you, System.IO.Path is the solution to the problem.

Comment: If people are wondering why Path.GetExtension, etc, ever *wouldn't* work: the various Path functions assume you're working with a Windows path... so they throw if your string contains any invalid characters, like '<'. I ran into a case just now where I wanted the extension of a file that came from somewhere where '<' was perfectly valid, and was going somewhere else where it also was, which brought me here looking for a clean way to just break a string on the last dot, without the framework trying to be smart and thinking it's a filename, so better do more validation.

Answer (score 3):

To get the path without the extension, use

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
```

and to get the extenstion (including the dot), use

```
Path.GetExtension(fileName)
```

EDIT:

Unfortunately GetFileNameWithoutExtension strips off the leading path, so instead you could use:

```
if (path == null)
{
    return null;
}
int length = path.LastIndexOf('.');
if (length == -1)
{
    return path;
}
return path.Substring(0, length);
```

Answer (score 2):

The string method [LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) maybe of some use to you here.

But the Path or FileInfo operators will be better suited for filename based operations.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're really looking for is [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method (System.IO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) but just for the heck of it:

```
string input = "foo.bar.foobar";
int lastDotPosition = input.LastIndexOf('.');

if (lastDotPosition == -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No dot found");
}
else if (lastDotPosition == input.Length - 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Last dot found at the very end");

}
else
{
    string firstPart = input.Substring(0, lastDotPosition);
    string lastPart = input.Substring(lastDotPosition + 1);

    Console.WriteLine(firstPart);
    Console.WriteLine(lastPart);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Path.GetExtension()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) should help you.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the LastIndexOf method which returns the last found position of a character. Then you can use Substring to extract what you want.

Answer (score 1):

String.LastIndexOf will return you the position of the dot if it ever exists in the string. You can then String.Substring methods to split the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string's method

LastIndexOf and substring to acomplish the task.