# save by filename as .csv or .json c#

Tags: c#, json, csv

I'm trying to program an administration program. I want to be able to save users' inputs as .json or .csv file. That is, if the user uses the file name ".. json", the file should be saved as Json, if not as csv. How could I enter this into my program?

```
public string Speichern(string path, string fileName)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dateiname eingeben!");
    fileName = (Console.ReadLine()); //ein eigenen Dateinamen wird zugewiesen
    Logger.Debug($"Der Dateiname lautet: {fileName}");

  
    string json = fileName + ".json";
    if (fileName == json)
    {
        LKW jsons = new LKW();
        Console.WriteLine(jsons.Ausgeben_JSON());

    }
    else
    {
        LKW cvss = new LKW();
        Console.WriteLine(cvss.Ausgeben_CSV());
    }


    String fullFilePathName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);//Speicherort und den Dateiname zusammenstellen
    String fContent = "";
    

    foreach (LKW lkw in liste)
    {
        fContent += lkw.Ausgeben_CSV() + "\r\n"; //Kodierung CarriageReturn Newline bei einem neuen LKw fügt einen Zeilenumbruch
    }
    foreach (LKW lkw in liste)
    {
        fContent += lkw.Ausgeben_JSON() + "\r\n";
    }
    File.WriteAllText(fullFilePathName, fContent);
    return fileName;
   }
```

Comment: You can use `var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName)` to see what kind of file the user wants, in case of an invalid result, simply fallback to `.csv`. related question: [Best way to break a string on the last dot on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086154/best-way-to-break-a-string-on-the-last-dot-on-c-sharp)

Comment: `EndsWith` would work just as well in this case, and saves one string instantiation.